How do I use the remesh modifier to join multiple objects topology?
I am trying to to join together these 3 rocks into 1 object (Like a big rock) using the Remesh Modifier
Obviously, I want the topology to be joined.
But as you can see in the screenshot, when I add the loop cut (the yellow loop in the pic) it does not go around the whole silhouette of the 3 rocks, just the first rock.
So am I doing anything wrong and are there any alternative ways of approaching this?


New edge loops can only be added where there are no triangles or n-gons.
Manually make your existing mesh flow continuously around the whole length to turn them into edge loops, then you should be able to add new loops that go all the way around.
Edit: I also now see that you joined the  three meshes, but didn't combine their topologies, so they are still three separate meshes.

In order to put an edge loops around all three of them, you will need to merge the vertices.
You can use vertex snapping and edge sliding (press G twice when selecting a loop) to line up new loops where there are none.

Once they loops are aligned, select the two vertices you want to combine, and press M to merge them. You can merge them at the point of the first vertex you select, or at the last, or at the center point between them (I used all three in this example).


How would I manually do that?

I've updated my answer, I hope that helps!
